# Rosjava - could not instantiate node

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody shine some light on this error?

`Exception in thread "main" org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Unable to instantiate node: TestNode at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:60) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.ros.internal.loader.CommandLineLoader can not access a member of class TestNode with modifiers "" at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95) at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:366) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325) at org.ros.internal.loader.CommandLineLoader.loadClass(CommandLineLoader.java:240) at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:54)`

Edit: Apparently roslaunch needs the class(es) to have public visibility.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36702/rosjava---could-not-instantiate-node/) by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you said, the RosRun class expects NodeMains to be public.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0